# YOLO v8 is out of memory error for batch size=1

Tags: pytorch, yolo, yolov8

While training a YoloV8 model, I get an error:

> torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate
> 24.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacty of 10.91 GiB of which 6.94 MiB is free. Including non-PyTorch memory, this process has 10.83 GiB memory
> in use. Of the allocated memory 10.51 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and
> 39.52 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid
> fragmentation. See documentation for Memory Management and
> PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

This happens under Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, Python 3.11.5, pytorch 2.1.0, ultralytics 8.0.203, batch size=1, GPU NVIDIA 1080 Ti (11 GBytes).

If I run the model on CPU on the same machine, it works (slowly, of course). Under Windows 10 and 1650 GPU (4 GB) it works fine.
Did you encounter such an issue? Any clue?

Comment: The error is pretty much clear that the GPU is running out of memory. Seems the model is larger than the available GPU Memory. Does the `1060Ti` 's memory is larger that `1080Ti` 's memory?

Comment: 1060Ti has 4 GB, 1080Ti has 11GB. At the moment of testing, I was the only one running something on the GPus. My bad, I said 1060Ti, it is actually 1650Ti, on a laptop. I added GPU memory details to the question.

Comment: What are the input image dimensions?

Comment: Does it run as float16 or float32?  Maybe on the old generation card it goes only fp32? But well still it should work on 11GB. Knowing the complex ultralytics jungle of settings, maybe the batch size is not actually one because you set it in a wrong place? :thinking:

Comment: @YakovDan: 640x640.

Comment: @hans: I printed a verbose log and it reports batch=1. I repeated the experiment on 4080 GPU (same pytorch/python/ubuntu version) and I got exactly the same failure.

Comment: Any luck, yet? Having the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem initially, but I was eventually able to fix it by setting `cache=False` in the `train()` method call.

Try this:

```py
model = YOLO('yolov8x.pt')
results = model.train(
    data='dataset.yaml',
    epochs=250,
    imgsz=640,
    batch=-1,
    device=0,
    cache=False   # cache=False is important!
)
```

To the question, why, I cannot give you a definitive answer, but I suspect that their caching algorithms cache all images on the GPU (which is obviously bad). By doing so, their auto-batching mechanism also doesn't work.